# Applying a difference in differences model with several treatment effects

Tags: regression, logistic, difference-in-difference

I am trying to empirically measure how online sentiment towards the state/government on Reddit amongst a specific group (e.g. [unemployed](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unemployment/)), changes in response to policies/programs announcements affecting them.

Specifically, I would like to know if it makes sense to use a Diff-in-Diff method to measure whether my Y outcome categorical variable: "online sentiment," on Reddit amongst the unemployed changes when, for instance, a $15 state-specific minimum wage is proposed or when states decide to extend their Covid unemployment insurance (UI), while others decide to end it.

The "online sentiment" categorizes overall sentiment towards the government into three subgroups: 1-positive, 2-negative, or 3-neutral/mixed.

Essentially, I am thinking that each policy announcement represents a pre & post treatment effect, but not sure if Diff-in-Diff is the best empirical approach in this case?
The treatment group would be the unemployed in a state where a $15 minimum wage is announced (e.g. Oregon), while the control/comparison group would be one that is unaffected by the policy's announcement/implementation.

Another way where I am measuring my Y variable is through a continuous Y variable with the volume of positive/negative Reddit posts engaged with the topic as my outcome variable. Specifically, tracking changes in the volume of positive posts in response to a minimum wage increase in the treated state, relative to a control state?

Comment: Your response variable is an ordered categorical variable so I am not sure if you can apply diff-in-diff. I would use an ordered logistic regression model to evaluate the effect of different covariates on the responses of the participants.

Comment: Thanks. I have added more details on how I might measure my outcome as a continuous variable.

Comment: Number of positive posts is not continuous either, it's discrete.  So you can use a Poisson regression model in that case.